# fullCalendar.js callback is for?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I have tried these code to show calendar event using fullcalendar.js and it works. This is the codepen: https://codepen.io/steve-ngai-chee-weng/pen/mdeYMxz

My issue is after I replaced the `events` property with the following code below, it doesn't show the calendar event. I have put a debugger and from there I could see the correct data being pushed into `events` array. One question is what is this `callback` and `if (callback) callback(events);` for?

```js
events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/Home/GetCalendarData',
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(result) {
      var events = [];

      $.each(result, function(i, data) {
        var startDate = moment(data.Start_Date).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
        var endDate = moment(data.End_Date).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
        debugger
        events.push({
          title: data.Title,
          description: data.Desc,
          start: startDate,
          end: endDate,
        });
      });
      if (callback) callback(events);

    }
  });
},
```

At `if (callback) callback(events);`, I can see that there are data in `events` but it is not showing up in the calendar and `callback` is undefined which I believe it is the root cause. May I know why `callback` is undefined?

Comment: The callback is used to "return" the value. Nowdays you would return a promise instead of passing in a callback but this was how we used to do it

Comment: What version of fullCalendar are you using? The method signature there is for version 3, but it you're finding the callback is undefined then maybe you're using version 4 which has a different structure. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function for the current (v4) documentation.

Comment: P.s. you should also be sending the provided start and end dates to your server, and your server should be filtering the list of events it returns based on those dates. Otherwise, over time, if you build up a lot of events then every time someone loads your page you'll end up downloading every event which was ever added to the calendar, and 99% of them won't be viewed by the user. That's not very efficient.

Comment: @ADyson. thanks. i notice there is a huge difference between version 3 and 4 and that v4 doesn't use ajax. hmm..for the link that you sent me, I do need to add this `superagent` ajax library, right?

Comment: @ADyson, can I use this `superagent` with MVC C#?

Comment: No you don't need superagent necessarily. Any AJAX library would do. You can continue using jQuery's AJAX library if you're comfortable with it, or you could switch to the built-in fetch()  functionality, or use another library like superagent or axios or any other. And MVC doesn't know or care which one you use - all it sees is the HTTP request generated by the library, it doesn't know what code was used to generate it.

Comment: P.s. "v4 doesn't use ajax" ... Not true. v4 doesn't use jQuery internally, but this has nothing to do with Ajax. Maybe you're referring to the specific jQuery function called $.ajax? That is just one implementation of the AJAX standard, as I've pointed out, there are many others. And again, just because fullCalendar stopped using jQuery within its code doesn't mean you can't continue to use it elsewhere in your code, including for fetching your events - you can write whatever you like in the event's callback, fullCalendar doesn't know or care, as long as it gets a list of events to read

Comment: @ADyson, do you have any example if I want to use $.ajax in version 4?

Comment: What do you mean? It's identical to how you are using it now. That's what my previous comments were attempting to explain. As long as jQuery is included in your page then you can use $.ajax. like I said, fullCalendar doesn't care what you use to fetch your events.

Comment: Yeah, I could use $.ajax in version 4, but problem is the `callback` is undefined. If I use version 3, no such issue.

Comment: That's nothing to do with $.ajax though. that's because you in haven't adapted your code yet to deal with the fact that the signature of the events function has changed, as I mentioned in my first comment. Have you checked the v4 documentation and noticed the changes?